# Self-synchronizing and -desynchronizing systems of oscillators

Tags: oscillators, interactions, complex-systems, coupled-oscillators

There are biological systems with adaptable frequencies that are able to synchronize their **frequencies**, mainly individuals (see e.g. [reproductive synchrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproductive_synchrony)). In this case, also the phase is typically synchronized. Populations on the other side occasionally *de*sychronize (see e.g. [periodical cicadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_cicadas)).

Furthermore, there are lots of physical systems (oscillators) with fixed frequency that are able to synchronize their **phases**. See e.g. [metronome synchronization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v5eBf2KwF8).

These are my questions:

1. What are the most simple physical oscillators with *adaptable*
   frequencies that are able to *synchronize frequencies* by some
   interaction?
2. What are the most simple physical oscillators with one common *fixed* frequency that are able to *desynchronize phases* by some interaction?

Comment: What's the meaning of "adaptable frequency" (possibly in mathematical terms)?

Comment: Would you allow, in your definition of adaptable, something like a (not-simple) pendulum? (In the sense that it does not always oscillate at a specific frequency given some initial condition.)

Comment: A pendulum of variable length would qualify.

Comment: By "desynchronize phases" you mean they start out with the same phases and evolve to a fixed phase difference? I think this happens, e.g., with two side-by-side pendula oscillating over a free platform.

Comment: @stafusa: Any example helps. I think of a set of oscillators that start with some random phases and evolve to pairwise maximally different phases.

Comment: @stafusa: Could you please be more specific. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker No, sorry. I can't remember where I saw this example and some searching now didn't reveal anything either. :-/

Comment: @stafusa: So could you please elaborate a bit? What are "side-by-side pendula" (coupled by a spring or what?) and what is "oscillating over a free platform"? Could you provide a sketch?

Comment: Like those in these figures: [here](http://docplayer.net/25031020-Pc235-winter-2013-chapter-12-coupled-oscillators-and-normal-modes-slide-1-of-49-chapter-12-coupled-oscillators-and-normal-modes.html) and [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/need-help-writing-translational-velocity-pendulums-due-movement-cart-q31525373). But I found something better and will soon post an (incomplete) answer.

Comment: @stafusa; Thanks for the interesting links!

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker My pleasure. I now added an answer that should give even more interesting links (even though, at the end of the day, they're scholarly references about a system you had already found on Youtube. :)). BTW, you might want to remove the reference to "[menstrual synchrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_synchrony)", which, as your own link says, "likely does not exist".

Comment: @stafusa: I followed your advice.

Comment: There is a simple model that shows that two pendula of the same length, attached to a platform under the influence of friction, will stabilize in a way where the pendulums will antiphase synchronize no matter what amplitude or phase they are initialized at. I am not sure if this qualifies under what you're looking for, but am happy to discuss it if so.

Answer (score 1):

A well-known simple model for synchronization in dynamical systems is the [Kuramoto–Daido model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto_model) of coupled oscillators.

A mechanical system that [has been shown](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1501118) ([e-print](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Ebard/classes/mth3380/syncpapers/metronome.pdf)) to be equivalent to the Kuramoto-Daido model is two pendulums on top of a free platform, a system which has recently [been revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02947):

[image]

and has been found to exhibit both in-phase and antiphase synchronizations, depending on its parameters, for instance (click to enlarge):

[image]

where $b$ measures the coupling strength (it's the ratio between one pendulum mass and the total mass $m/M$) and $r$ quantifies the nonlinearity of the pendulums (and "can be more usefully interpreted as a driving strength in its own right").

As for frequency synchronization, also called "mode locking", it's in general driven by high connectivity or high coupling strength. Probably the sine map is one of the simplest examples (though a toy model, rather than a specific physical system) to exhibit it. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/31.1826) ([e-print](https://biocomplexity.indiana.edu/jglazier/docs/papers/04_Quasi_Periodicity.pdf)), although old, provides a very readable introduction to the system. For stochastic systems, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1500497) considers frequency and phase synchronization on the driven noisy harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer that gives me a lot of reading. Unfortunately, my question was for systems a) starting with different frequencies and ending up with the same frequency and b) having the same frequency, starting with random (and partially the same) phases and ending up with "maximally different" phases. Maybe I didn't manage to state this clearly enough? (I'll check if your last link answers a.)

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Take your time. The OP is clear, I guess **I** didn't make it clear how I'm answering it. The last reference includes oscillators with different frequencies synchronizing via noise. And the 1988 paper is on an oscillator adjusting its frequency to an external forcing — which is conceptually similar, but arguably easier to understand on a first contact, than two oscillators adjusting their frequencies to each other. And I understood that with "maximally different" phases you meant $\pi$, and then that's the "antiphase" the 2020 manuscript describes.

Comment: This it what I could have made more clearly - and easily so: with "maximally different" I mean "equally distributed over $2\pi$". As an analogy: Consider some $n$ positively charged identical objects that are freely moveable along a ring. Their positions will be equally distributed over $2\pi$.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Hmm.. OK. So, for two oscillators antiphase is what you want, but you also want something that generalizes to more oscillators. Is that correct? Then what about waves propagating on a chain of harmonic oscillators coupled with springs?